# What is the syntax for floor division in Julia?

Tags: julia, floor-division

In Python 5//2 is a floor division.

In Julia:

`5//2`

Returns

`5//2`

How can I do floor division in Julia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
julia> 5 ÷ 2
2
```

The character `÷` can be entered by typing `\div` and pressing Tab.

On the other hand the operator `//` is used to create rational numbers.

The `÷` sign represents a  `div` operator. If the number is negative you need to use `fld` to the the actual floor division. You could assign it to one of unused operators for comfortable use:

```
julia> ∺ = fld
fld (generic function with 10 methods)

julia> -5 ∺  2
-3
```

Comment: might be good to mention `div(5,2)` for a non-unicode solution.

Comment: Does not work for negative dividends.

In Python, -3//2 evaluates to -2. In Julia, div(-3,2) evaluates to -1.

Comment: "Does not work" is a strong way to say "has a different rounding rule than Python".

Comment: Given that the original question was about floor division, "does not work" is fair. That solution does not work for floor division.

Comment: The difference between `div` and `fld` is that `div` rounds to zero by default (configurable with the third argument) whereas `fld` always rounds down.

Comment: you are right - I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
julia> floor(5/2)
2.0

julia> floor(Int64, 5/2)
2
```

At the julia> prompt type '?' and then 'floor()' and again '? div()' to see what has already been mentioned.

Comment: floor(Int64,x/y) will generate an `InexactError` if x/y is large.  E.g. `floor(Int64,x/1)`

Answer (score 2):

In Julia, use `fld`:

```
julia> fld(5,2)
2

julia> fld(-5,2)
-3

julia> fld(5,-2)
-3

julia> fld(-5,-2)
2
```